# validate three unique columns togethernot working in update for same column

Tags: laravel

i made three columns unique together and this is my validation

```
  public function validEdit($request ,$id)
{
    $color = $request->get('color');
    $size_id = $request->get('size_id');
    $name = $request->get('name');
    return 
    Validator::make($request->all(),
    [
    'name' => 'required|min:4|string|unique:products,name,NULL,id,color,'.$color.',size_id,'.$size_id,',id,'.$id,
    'description'=>'required|min:4',
    'quantity'=>'required|numeric',
    'subcategory_id'=> 'required',
    'category_id'=> 'required',
    'price'=> 'required|numeric',
    'color'=>'required|unique:products,color,NULL,id,name,'.$name.',size_id,'.$size_id,',id,'.$id,
    'size_id'=>'required|unique:products,size_id,NULL,id,name,'.$name.',color,'.$color,',id,'.$id,
    'images.*'=>'image:png,jpg,jpeg',
    // 'photos.*'=>'image:png,jpg,jpeg',
    'cover'=> 'image:png,jpg,jpeg'
    ]);
```

it works fin , but how i can make it skip validate for the same column

thanks

Comment: which columns are unique? you mean that let's say you have 2 unique columns, "unique(A, B)" so that a pair of AB appears only one time?

Comment: What did you tried to do? According to Laravel Validation docs, unique validation works this way: `unique:tableName,columnName`. So why there are so many additional parameters to this validation?

Comment: @Berto99 
i have three unique columns together , i need to validate if this three are not exists on other row , the three of them but not on this column